# Cannot read property "length" from undefined in Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to make a custom function that searches a column for a specific number than searches for a yes or a no in the same row in a different column.

```
function avgLoop(a, b, v) {

  //a is original range, b is value to find, v is where to find 
  var avg = 1;
  var d =0;
  for (var i =0; i < a.length; i++) 
  {
    if(a[i] == b)
    {
      if(v[i] == "yes")
      {
        avg +=1
        d++;
      }
      if(v[i] == "No")
      {
        d++;
      }
     }
   }
   return avg/d;
}
```

Comment: Please add the data source.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-scrip

Comment: The problem is in the code that's calling this, it's not passing an array as the first argument.

Comment: If `a` is a value range - it would be 2-D, so to compare values you need to do `if(a[i] [j]== b)`. Please specify which line throws the error and what your v looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You specify in your commented remarks in the code that `a` is the original range.  You cannot request the length of a range, however, you can call the length of an array.  Just change the code at the beginning of the function to the following, it should work just fine, providing that the variable a is a range and there are no other errors in the code or inputs:

```
function avgLoop(ssrange, b, v) {
var avg = 1;
var d =0;
var a= ssrange.getValues();
for ....  // continue your script from here
```